# How to specify feature name for sklearn dump_svmlight_file in python?

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, libsvm, svmlight

Docs:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html

svmlight follows the data format:

```
<target> <feature:value> <feature:value>
```

With the data:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
b = [8,9]
```

Running the command:

```
dump_svmlight_file(a,b,'test.txt')
```

Outputs the following:

```
8 0:1 1:2 2:3
9 0:4 1:5 2:6
```

I would like to know if there is a way to specify the feature name rather than have it increment from 0, I would like to have something like the following as my result:

```
1 10:5 50:15 100:50
0 10:15 25:5 75:15
1 20:5 40:5 60:5
```

Does the dump_svmlight_file command have such a capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `dump_svmlight_file` does not have that option built in. [Source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7389dba/sklearn/datasets/svmlight_format.py#L385)

You can just specify whether the feature names should start at 0 or 1 using the parameter `zero_based`. 
[Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.dump_svmlight_file.html)

I would suggest you not to try dump the file with actual feature names, which would unnecessarily increase size of the file. Instead pickle your feature names as a separate one and then join them.